# Tour planning job pickup/delivery times

Tags: here-api

I am wondering if there are multiple pickup times and multiple delivery times specified do they have to be the same length so they are paired with each other? Or are the pickup times and delivery times considered separately by the solver?

```
plan.jobs.tasks.pickups[0].places[0].times
plan.jobs.tasks.deliveries[0].places[0].times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, they do not have to have the same duration, they are completely independent.

These time windows only indicate the time in which the action can be carried out (pickup or delivery), so having a scenario in which the collection time is between 10 and 11 in the morning and the delivery time is between 2 and 6 in the afternoon is perfectly valid.

In the following link, you can find a section in which the meaning of several of the concepts involved in this API is precisely detailed:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/3.7.0/dev_guide/topics/concepts/problem.html

I also invite you to review our documentation regarding this API where several examples and detailed information are provided:

- Dev guide: https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/3.7.0/dev_guide/index.html
- API reference: https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/3.7.0/api-reference-swagger.html